# How do I reposition a groupbox on a form?

Tags: c#, winforms

I have two group boxes, the top one is collapsible. I want to adjust the layout of the lower group box when the upper group box collapses or expands.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `Dock` property: set the first to `Top` and the second to `Fill`

Answer (score 0):

In addition to @Marco's suggestion, another option is the [FlowLayoutPanel](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zah8ywcc.aspx). It's useful when you want to ensure nearby controls adapt to fill the space when a control is resized.

Answer (score 0):

A `SplitContainer` can help in this type of display.

```
splitContainer1.Orientation = Orientation.Horizontal;
splitContainer1.IsSplitterFixed = true;
```

And then in each panel in the `SplitContainer` control, you place your `GroupBoxes` with both their `Dock` settings set to `Fill`.

When collapsing the top panel, you let the `SplitContainer` handle it:

```
splitContainer1.Panel1Collapsed = !splitContainer1.Panel1Collapsed;
```